# Support for multilanguage in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, multilingual

I am just getting a run time error in the second line.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
rm = new ResourceManager("Resources.Default.apsx", 
         System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(
             "E:\\New folder\\multi_lang\\multi_lang\\App_LocalResources")));
ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

The error message says that access is denied from the following path metioned or the file is in read-only mode. I am not getting what's wrong in my code.

Comment: Did you mean for the file extension to be apsx, should it not be aspx?

Comment: problem is with the path...not with the extension

Comment: Unless you have explicitly authorized the user the app pool is running under to have access to that directory, it will fail with an access denied message.

The directory you have looks like it is outside of the directory the application is actually deployed to.

Answer (score 1):

try with this code, you don't need to load your ressource file if you work on version 2.0 or 3.5 or 4

```
String language = "en-US";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
```

Or in your configuration

```
<globalization culture="en-US" />
```

Or use this in your page default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Culture="en-US" %>
```

Comment: You can to add section configuration without coding, add in your page culture